# Accessing Bundle from React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I need to pass some data (specifically, the contents of a received SMS but I'm not sure how relevant that is) from "Android land" (i.e. native code) to React Native activity. Now, I believe that in native code, using a bundle is the right option but is there a way to access that data from the ReactActivity?

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.example.domain", "com.example.domain.MainActivity");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("foobar", AnyValue);  
context.startActivity(i);
```

Can I access foobar from RN code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/CentaurWarchief/react-native-android-sms-listener.

Usage looks like this:

```
import SmsListener from 'react-native-android-sms-listener'

SmsListener.addListener(message => {
  console.info(message)
})
```

Or create your own module with method that returns a promise with SMS content. See documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html